# Date comparison help in Entity Framework Codefirst

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

```
    using (var attendanceContext = new AttendanceAppContext())
    {
        var compareLogin = attendanceContext.Attendances.FirstOrDefault(u =>
        u.LoginDate == DateTime.Now.Date &&
        u.Employee.Username == user.Username);
```

The code is continued and the compareLogin variable is used later but here an exception is thrown that says: 
"The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializer, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Please help and tell me how I should compare the dates from the database.

Comment: waht is Emloyee.Username. Are you joining to another table here?

Comment: Oh no its just an object called Employee of Employee type. I defined it as " public Employee Employee { get; set; } ". There is another class Employee, I'm linking this with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) function:

```
using (var attendanceContext = new AttendanceAppContext())
{
    var compareLogin = attendanceContext.Attendances.FirstOrDefault(u =>
    EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(u.LoginDate) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now) &&
    u.Employee.Username == user.Username);
}
```

Also if `u.LoginDate` is date without time in your database you may try to use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now.Date`. If it doesn't work just extract it into some variable (e.g `var today = DateTime.Today`) and use it in your LINQ expression.

Comment: I want to compare it specifically with the current day's date and not time. Because later I want to see if someone has logged in to the server already once in the same day. So how can that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to be:

```
 var compareLogin = (from a in attendanceContext.Attendances.FirstOrDefault
                     where a.LoginDate == DateTime.Now.Date && a.Employee.Username == user.Username
                     select a).ToList();
```

Comment: This is code is showing error. I am using DbSet type objects here and the compiler keeps suggesting that I must use FirstOrDefault().